# Having trouble loop through a list <set <pair > >

Tags: java

Here is how I declared my list. it.next() appears to be returning my set when it should be returning a pair (which is a string,int pair) in one of my lists. Any ideas?
The method getFirst() is undefined for the type Object..It seems that if I do this , it fixes this.

String m=((Pair) it.next()).getFirst();

```
List <HashSet<Pair>>  addresses = new ArrayList <HashSet<Pair>> ();

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Iterator it = (addresses.get(i)).iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()){
        String m = it.next().getFirst()); //getFirst returns a string
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks allright. Care to debug step by step and see what exactly it is you are getting?

Comment: it's a compile error, not runtime

Comment: In your code, `it.next()` is a `Pair` object. Not sure what you are asking... If you have a compilation error, please post it.

Comment: Ok, so what's the compile error? You said you goy a String, not that the compiler complained

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, it compiles just fine:

```
List<Set<Pair>> addresses = new ArrayList<Set<Pair>>();
// fill the list of addresses

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Iterator<Pair> it = addresses.get(i).iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        String m = it.next().getFirst();
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll have to populate the list of addresses with sets of pairs for the above to do something useful.

Comment: @user1526556 you're welcome! If this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to accept it by clicking on the check mark to its left.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to remove the extra parenthesis at the end of the line inside the while loop. It should look like this

`String m = it.next().getFirst();`